# Unable to use Bokeh plot's 'desired_num_ticks'. Error thrown is " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'desired_num_ticks' "

Tags: python, bokeh

As per this document I understand that 'desired_num_ticks' is not deprecated and that it expects an integer.

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html

But I get error for the below plot. (Please note, when I comment ' f.ygrid[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 1 ', everything works fine and I get the Bokeh plot)

```
print(df) # the data that i'm using
                       Start                        End
0  2020-06-14 11:30:05.940200 2020-06-14 11:30:06.244248
1  2020-06-14 11:30:06.276542 2020-06-14 11:30:06.371198
2  2020-06-14 11:30:06.516061 2020-06-14 11:30:06.547580
3  2020-06-14 11:30:06.579995 2020-06-14 11:30:06.612236
4  2020-06-14 11:30:06.644278 2020-06-14 11:30:06.676330
5  2020-06-14 11:30:10.243353 2020-06-14 11:30:10.755898
```

```
from detection1dot2 import df     # import the dataframe
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

f=figure(x_axis_type='datetime', height=500, width=500, sizing_mode="stretch_width", title='Motion Graph')
f.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
f.ygrid[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 1

f.quad(left=df["Start"], right=df["End"], bottom=0, top=1)
output_file("motion.html")
```

When I run the script I get the below error.

```
   f.ygrid[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 1
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'desired_num_ticks'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the grid does not have an explicitly set ticker. I think it's not documented properly - `Grid.ticker` is used to override the corresponding axis ticker that grids use by default. So if you have a single Y axis, you can just use

```py
f.yaxis.ticker.desired_num_ticks = 1
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```py
f.ygrid[0].ticker.desired_num_ticks = 1
```

Use

```py
f.ygrid.ticker = [0,1] # pass a list of desired ticks
```

It will work